# Trouble pasting specific fields using awk

Tags: awk

I'm using different ways to paste from a file into a script. I'm trying to use awk to paste from the first line of a file, however I want to only paste the 2,3,4 field. 
Here is my code

```
echo "Curve Name" $(awk 'NR==1'  testfile  )
```

Here is the output

```
Curve Name F gge0006x gge0001y gge0001z
```

I want to get rid of that F. 
The file that I'm reading it from starts with the F.

What I want is

```
Curve Name gge0006x gge0001y gge0001z
```

What should I add to get it to print this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `echo` to print `Curve Name` and then have to get rid of the first field of the line, why not simply *replace* the field you don't want with the text that you do want?

```
awk 'NR==1 {$1 = "Curve Name"; print; exit}'  testfile
```

Comment: IfI wanted to do this but for multiple files, same column, how would I do this??

Comment: I notice that you have opened a separate question for this [pasting with awk - Can't paste from multiple files on the same line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434379/pasting-with-awk-cant-paste-from-multiple-files-on-the-same-line) - I won't attempt to answer it here

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==1 {$1=""; print}'  testfile
```